# Lubuntu Google Chrome not opening

Tags: linux, chrome, lubuntu, kiosk

Right now I have a kiosk apps set up on a mini PC with lubuntu 18.10. The apps run on Chrome. I create a command to autostart Chrome instance everytime the PC starts up.

But sometimes, Chrome doesn't start, and from logs I know the error is this:

```
[1680:1680:0830/083742.498300:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(313)] invalid EDID:
human unreadable char in name

[1715:1715:0830/083742.790840:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(368)]
InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process
gpu-process. /home/soltova/Documents/chrome.sh: line 17:  1680 Killed 
/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-web-security --test-type
--user-data-dir --kiosk --incognito http://localhost/html12/
```

How do I approach this issue, so that everytime the PC start up, Google Chrome shows up?

Start up script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

exec > /home/soltova/Documents/chrome-run.log 
exec 2> /home/soltova/Documents/chrome-run.err
#xset dpms force off 
function online {   ## Test if online - prototype code  
 wget -q -O /dev/null --timeout=5 http://www.google.com  
 return $?
}

until online do   sleep 5 done

#xset dpms force on     
/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-web-security --test-type --user-data-dir --kiosk --incognito http://localhost/html12/
```

Comment: what does the startup script look like? can you update your question with it?

Comment: updated my start up script

Answer (score 0):

There is a common Google Chrome error when trying to run it in Linux due to Chrome’s GPU usage.

Unfortunately there isn’t a clear fix yet, this is a is an easy solution to make it possible to use Chrome browser when the following error message appears.

This error affects to all Chrome versions:

- Google Chrome stable
- Google Chrome beta
- Chromium

### Solution

The easiest solution is to avoid using GPU hardware acceleration with the following flags: `--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer`

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```

Parameter `--disable-gpu` [definition](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?q=kDisableGpu&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=141):

> Disables GPU hardware acceleration. If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch

Parameter `--disable-software-rasterizer` [definition](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?q=kDisableGpu&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=279):

> Disables the use of a 3D software rasterizer

Comment: i see, but does using this flag will have issues in rendering my chrome ? because i am actually running unity on web for my app, isnt disabling gpu making it more slower?

Comment: not sure, presumably not. please also see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=906455#c14

Comment: Allright thanks for the help!

Comment: hey man, i tried this and it does significantly lower the performance to render image/videos, so it looks a bit laggy....but i do some research and found out about --no-sandbox flags, do you know something about this?